NSum result quite different from Sum. Euler Maclaurin won‘t work!
I have just computed this finite sum:
N[Sum[Sin[1000003451/k], {k, 1, 1000}], 100]

And the result is:

-42.57582822927303221782613293712000247819591467928837841944661143978383722857210408949437814658891999.

But when I use NSum:
NSum[Sin[1000003451/k], {k, 1, 1000}, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin",
  WorkingPrecision -> 24, AccuracyGoal -> 24,
  PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, NSumTerms -> 20]

the result is 1.0.
I wonder why NSum result is so different from Sum.
If I don't want to change NSumTerms too much.
Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?  Is it possible that Euler-Maclaurin can't handle this kind of summation?
Can I somehow use "Richardson" or "LevinRule", because I cannot find them under NSum function.

NSum[Sin[1000003451/k], {k, 1, 1000}, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin",   WorkingPrecision -> 24, AccuracyGoal -> 24,   PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, NSumTerms -> 1600]
According to @LouisB's answer, you should increase NSumTerms?

If NSumTerms -> 1600, then what is the difference between NSum and Sum?
What is the meaning of NSumTerms, the number of first terms of Sin[1000003451/k], or the number of first terms of Euler-Maclaurin expansion?

Notice that NSum produced a warning/error message that Euler-Maclaurin has failed to converge.  Many more terms are required for convergence of the NSum, as shown in the following visualization.
data = Table[{nterms, NSum[Sin[1000003451/k], {k, 1, 1000}, 
    Method -> "EulerMaclaurin",WorkingPrecision -> 24, AccuracyGoal -> 24,
    PrecisionGoal -> Infinity, NSumTerms -> nterms]},{nterms, 80, 1600, 40}];

data//Last  (*  {1600,-42.5758282292730322178261}  *)

ListPlot[data, Frame->True, GridLines->Automatic, PlotRange->All]



Thanks for your comment. If so many terms have to be used, then why not just use Sum? I  want to know how to get the right answer using NSum.
